# Java Spring -- identify syntax errors at compile-time (in Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am new to Spring and just now learning to use it in a piece of legacy code. If I use bad syntax (as in I mistype a bean name or I use the wrong syntax to construct things like enums) then the code will compile fine.

This makes sense, since they're just XML files loaded at run-time.

For me, this is a big issue because my service can take up to 5 minutes to run, even though it compiles instantly. And there is no need for this, because all of the syntax errors can be known before the service is run. I shouldn't need an exception to know about it.

In Eclipse, is there a plugin or feature I can use to have compilation fail if my Spring syntax is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Take a look at [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) (Spring Tool Suite) - it is a n Eclipse special bundle for working with Spring. It has the context XML validation plugin and many other goodies.